# How to output everything AFTER a specific string?

Tags: c++

For example, I have a winsock application that's consistently receiving packets with "*USER" in them. Everything after "*USER" is different in each packet, so how can I output everything after "*USER"? Thanks in advance.

Also important to note that "*USER"'s position in the packet is different each time.

```
                    size_t start2 = rData.find("*USER");
                    size_t end2 = rData.find(";");

                    cout << rData.substr(start2, end2 - start2);
```

Comment: You can just add the length of *USER string to your start2 variable.`size_t start2 = rData.find("*USER") + strlen("*USER");`

Comment: Use `strlen("*USER")` or just add 5 to your start2 variable. Try code from my previous comment.